# Maven "Non-resolvable parent POM" when pom is already in Maven Central

Tags: java, maven, parent-pom

I have an open source project (https://github.com/mikera/vectorz) that uses a parent pom that is deployed on Maven Central (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.mikera%7Cmikera-pom%7C0.2.0%7Cpom)

However I have started to get a strange error:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project net.mikera:vectorz:0.39.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Mike\git\vect
orz\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact net.mikera:mikera
-pom:pom:0.2.0 in clojars.org (http://clojars.org/repo) and 'parent.relativePath
' points at wrong local POM @ line 9, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableMo
delException
```

What could be causing this? Note that:

- I'm 99% certain the parent pom has been successfully released on Central
- `clojars` repo shouldn't even be required for the build
- I'm running on Windows (though the issue seems to be affecting others on Linux too)
- I have had projects like this working previously, however I recently upgraded to Maven 3.2.2 - could that be causing this error?

P.S. I tried checking my local `.m2` repository and all it contains is a `.lastUpdated` file with the folloing content:

```
#NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Mon Aug 11 13:23:30 SGT 2014
http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1407734610196
http\://clojars.org/repo/.lastUpdated=1407734609627
http\://clojars.org/repo/.error=
http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked on central that the parent pom really is there?  Alternatively, have you overridden the repos in your pom or settings.xml such that maven is not checking central?

Comment: I cloned your repository and could build it without any problems using parent version 0.1.0 and 0.2.0.

Comment: OK thanks for the info! I think I've managed to get it working now... still not 100% sure what caused this, maybe some sort of caching issue

Comment: @mikera, So has the problem been solved? Post the solution.